# Why is GIT not replacing CRLF with LF on writing to the working directory, although core.autocrlf is set to input?

Tags: git, core.autocrlf

Recently I fiddled around with gits option `core.autocrlf` und set it to `input`. I tested if the configuration parameter is set correctly:

```
$ git config --global core.autocrlf
input

$ git config core.autocrlf
input
```

Then to test gits behavior I deleted all contents of the project folder (except of course the folder `.git`) and made a

```
git reset --hard HEAD
```

But my editor tells me, the line endings ares still `CRLF`.

Why?

(I am on Ubuntu and use Atom as editor. The editors statement seems to be valid, as when I tell it to change all line endings to `LF`, git tells me that every line of the file was changed.)

To understand more about the whole topic i read this enlighting article:

[Mind the End of Your Line](http://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`core.autocrlf=input` will only adopt file endings when adding them to the index (and commiting them).

It will not modify the files on the way to the workspace. You would need to use `true` for that - and mostly for older Mac and Windows where the native line ending is not LF.

But most likely .gitattributes is the better system for you, as discussed in the article you mentioned.

Comment: I made a change to `file.a` and commited it. Then I deleted the contents of the working directory again. Did `git reset --hard HEAD` checked the line endings. Still `CRLF`. Now, by your suggestion `file.a` was edited, changes written to the object database, and written back to the working directory. All with `core.autocrlf input`. Shouldn't it do the trick now?

Comment: Maybe the file is not recognized as a text file. You can use the following command, it will report the file if it is recognized as text: `git grep -I --name-only --untracked -e . -- file.a`.

Comment: It recognizes it as text file. It does a correct diff. Maybe the conversion on line endings just happens when a new file gets added to the index?

Comment: Maybe, too lazy to try :) I typically fix up the line endings once by hand with dos2unix.

Comment: I tested it. Yes, it does change the line endings only when adding a new file with `CRLF` endings and commiting it. But not even with snippets with `CRLF` endings.

Comment: BTW: git 2.8.0 added a new feature `it ls-files --eol <files>`

Answer (score 2):

From [the manual](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration):

> If you’re on a Linux or Mac system that uses LF line endings, then you don’t want Git to automatically convert them when you check out files; however, if a file with CRLF endings accidentally gets introduced, then you may want Git to fix it. You can tell Git to **convert CRLF to LF on commit** but not the other way around by setting core.autocrlf to input

It only does the conversion on commit, apparently.

Answer (score 2):

***`core.autocrlf=input`***

**Will not** update existing files. It will only set **added** files line endings to the desired format.

> ***`core.autocrlf`***
>
> Setting this variable to `true` is almost the same as setting the text attribute to `auto` on all files except that text files are not guaranteed to be normalized: files that contain CRLF in the repository will not be touched.
>
> Use this setting if you want to have CRLF line endings in your working directory even though the repository does not have normalized line endings.
>
> ***`This variable can be set to input, in which case no output conversion is performed`***.

---

> ***`core.autocrlf=input`***
>
> This means that Git will process all text files and make sure that CRLF is replaced with LF ***when writing*** that file to the object database. It will not, however, do the reverse.